Funcion de aws signature v4 no calza con el servicio cognito de aws
actualmente estoy intentando acceder a la api de cognito para gestionar grupos y usuarios. Mediante POSTMAN funciona todo OK, pero cuando intento realizar el AWS Signature por codigo, no hace el match con el del servicio.
"__type" => "InvalidSignatureException"
  "message" => "
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
"

he seguido paso a paso la documentación:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_sigv-create-signed-request.html
y no logro encontrar el problema...
dejo la función que tengo actualmente para realizar el signature:
private function aws_signature_v4($body = '' , $headers = []){
    $timestamp = Carbon::now('UTC')->format('Ymd\THis\Z');
    $date = substr($timestamp, 0, 8);
    ksort($headers);
    $canonical_headers = [];
    foreach($headers as $key => $value){
        $canonical_headers[] = strtolower($key).':'.trim($value);
    }
    $canonical_headers = implode("\n", $canonical_headers)."\n";
    $signed_headers = implode(';', array_map('strtolower', array_keys($headers)));
    $path = parse_url(env('AWS_COGNITO_ENDPOINT'), PHP_URL_PATH) ?: '/';
    $payload_hash = hash('sha256', $body);
    $canonical_request = "POST\n" . 
                        $path . "\n" .
                        "\n" . 
                        $canonical_headers . "\n" .
                        $signed_headers . "\n" .
                        $payload_hash;
    $hashed_canonical_request = hash('sha256', $canonical_request);
    $scope = $date.'/'.env('AWS_COGNITO_REGION').'/cognito-idp/aws4_request';
    $string_to_sign  = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'."\n".$timestamp."\n".$scope."\n".$hashed_canonical_request;
    $kDate = hash_hmac('sha256', $date, 'AWS4'.env('AWS_COGNITO_USER_SECRET_KEY'), true);
    $kRegion = hash_hmac('sha256', env('AWS_COGNITO_REGION'), $kDate, true);
    $kService = hash_hmac('sha256', 'cognito-idp', $kRegion, true);
    $kSigning = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', $kService, true);
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $kSigning, $string_to_sign);
    $authorization = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 ' .
                'Credential=' . env('AWS_COGNITO_USER_ACCESS_KEY') . '/' . $scope . ', ' .
                'SignedHeaders=' . $signed_headers . ', ' .
                'Signature=' . $signature;
    return $authorization;
}

